# How to Convert response body into Json Form Sealed Class Api handle

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

When I am using sealed class to get response from server then I am getting below response

```
 SendOtp(data=SendOtpData(created_at=null, id=0, mobile=[The selected mobile is invalid.], otp=0, user_id=0, validity=null), message=Empty or wrong field! validation error, status=2, success=false)
```

I know very well to read object from jsonResponse but I dont know how to read it.

Now I am sharing that where I am getting above response

```
package com.example.cgreenwithallkotlin.data.network

import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.Response

interface BlindApiCall {

    suspend fun <T: Any> blindApiCall(
        apiCall : suspend () -> Response<T>
    ): NetworkResult<T>{
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                val response = apiCall()
                val body = response.body()
                if (response.isSuccessful && body != null) {
                    println("body = $body")

                        NetworkResult.Success(body)

                }else if (response.errorBody() != null){
                    val errorObj = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.charStream().readText())
                    NetworkResult.ApiError(response.code(), errorObj.getString("message"))
                }
                else {
                    NetworkResult.Error(code = response.code(), message = response.message())
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                NetworkResult.Error(code = e.code(), message = e.message())
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                NetworkResult.Exception(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above class I got that reposnse in body.